# Rails acces external API through a get request from another get request(requestception)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, http, request

I have a rails client-server app that also needs to get some data from an external api with a authentication token. The authentication token is stored on my rails server.

Basically want I want to do is: when a user triggers a get request from my client-side to my server-side,  I get some data from my database on the server and I want to get some data from the external api en send both sets of data as a response back to client.

But I'm not sure if it's a good Idea to send a get request from another get request like that.

Is that how this is typically done or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

- Create an ActiveJob job with the GET request to external API.
- Have your client's GET request to trigger the job.
- Collect all the data you need and send response back to client

Comment: Why create an `ActiveJob` for just a `GET` request?

Comment: You are relying on external API. If his client has many visitors generating the get request the app is potentially going to get bogged down waiting for external API to respond. So if you are doing an external API request often, you should probably background it, and have it update your models.

Or you could put the external get request into the view code to be executed in the visitor's browser.

Just do some performance testing and make the decision based on that.

Comment: From my understanding active job runs parallel and I can't wait for it to finish to send the data in the response. How would that work? Another possibility is to trigger the job with the first request and send a second request to get the data when the job is finished. But how do I know when the job has finished  from the client side?

Comment: What are you using for your front end? And what exactly are you retrieving?

Comment: My front-end is angularJS based. Data I'm retrieving from my own database is  location/office building data. This includes addresses, some photos, geo coordinates etc. Data from the external api is reservations for each room in the building.

Comment: yeah, use activejob to check the reservations on a schedule (every 10min, half hour, daily, or what have you) and update your model. This is probably a more reasonable solution. Otherwise you could do your checks in the browser, but if you have thousands of visitors, you could potentially do nasty things to the external api.